# python: call a set of functions specified in a configuration file

Tags: python, json, class

I have a json file where I specify some functions that need to be called within the compute method of a class.

The json file look like this:

```
{"function_definition": ["function_1","function_2","function_3"]}
```

I read this file in the `__init__` method of my class as follow:

```
def __init__(self,filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        variables = json.load(f)
    for key, value in variables.items():
                setattr(self, key, value)
```

Now I need to call these functions inside the `compute` method.
I tried to do like this:

```
def function_1(self,parameter):
    function_1 = 1*parameter
    return function_1

def function_2(self,parameter):
    function_2 = 2*parameter
    return function_2

def function_3(self,parameter):
    function_3 = 3*parameter
    return function_3

def compute(self,parameter):

    output_function= {}
    for index_function in range(0,len(self.function_definition)):
        output_function[self.function_definition[index_feature]] = 
         self.features_to_compute[index_feature](parameter)
```

but I get:

```
TypeError: 'unicode' object is not callable
```

What is the right way to call a function specified in my conf file as a string?

Comment: Even if `self.features_to_compute[index_feature]` returned the function itself (and it doesn't. It returns the function's name as it is in the json file), where are  functions *defined*?

Comment: Leaving the design problem aside here, where are the functions defined? In the same module? In another module? In the latter case, is the module already imported?

Comment: @timegeb, I ve edited my question... the functions are defined as methods of the same class...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Leaving the design problems here aside, you are looking for `getattr`. You can use it to get an object's attributes (methods, in your case) by name. Afterwards, you can call the return value of `getattr`.

Demo:

```
>>> class foo(object):
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.function_definition = ['function1', 'function2']
...     def function1(self):
...         print('hi')
...     def function2(self):
...         print('bye')
...     def compute(self):
...         for fname in self.function_definition:
...             getattr(self, fname)()
... 
>>> foo().compute()
hi
bye
```

Comment: Thank you! do you have a suggestion for the design? :) I didn't understand if there is something wrong in my design..

Comment: I know too little about your code to judge that, *sometimes* calling a function/method by name is the easiest solution, so your design is not necessarily bad. However, looking at your `__init__` method it looks like you are trying to save and restore whole objects with JSON. Have you looked into more direct approaches like `pickle`?